# Google 3.32 causes MapOverlay error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Everything works fine using 3.31, but when I use the 3.32 or 3.33 script my overlay fails to load. Here is my custom overlay class:

```
    function MapOverlay(bounds, image, map) {

        // Now initialize all properties.
        var sw = new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.southWest.latitude, bounds.southWest.longitude);
        var ne = new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.northEast.latitude, bounds.northEast.longitude);
         //if (westernCorner.longitude > easternCorner.longitude)
        this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);
        this.image = image;
        this.map = map;

        // We define a property to hold the image's
        // div. We'll actually create this div
        // upon receipt of the add() method so we'll
        // leave it null for now.
        this.div = null;

        // Explicitly call setMap() on this overlay
        this.setMap(map);
    }

    MapOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

    MapOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

        // Note: an overlay's receipt of onAdd() indicates that
        // the map's panes are now available for attaching
        // the overlay to the map via the DOM.

        // Create the DIV and set some basic attributes.
        var div = document.createElement('DIV');
        div.style.border = "none";
        div.style.borderWidth = "0px";
        div.style.position = "absolute";

        // Create an IMG element and attach it to the DIV.
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = this.image;
        img.style.width = "100%";
        img.style.height = "100%";
        div.appendChild(img);

        // Set the overlay's div_ property to this DIV
        this.div = div;

        // We add an overlay to a map via one of the map's panes.
        // We'll add this overlay to the overlayImage pane.
        var panes = this.getPanes();
        panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
    };

    MapOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

        // Size and position the overlay. We use a southwest and northeast
        // position of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
        // We need to retrieve the projection from this overlay to do this.
        var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

        // Retrieve the southwest and northeast coordinates of this overlay
        // in latlngs and convert them to pixels coordinates.
        // We'll use these coordinates to resize the DIV.
        var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds.getSouthWest());
        var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds.getNorthEast());

        // Resize the image's DIV to fit the indicated dimensions.
        var div = this.div;
        div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
        div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
        console.log("ne.x: " + ne.x + " sw.x " + sw.x + " width: " + (ne.x - sw.x));
        div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
        div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
    };

    MapOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
        this.div.parentNode.removeChild(this.div);
        this.div = null;
    };

    // Note that the visibility property must be a string enclosed in quotes
    MapOverlay.prototype.hide = function() {
        if (this.div) {
            this.div.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    };

    MapOverlay.prototype.show = function() {
        if (this.div) {
            this.div.style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    };
```

And here is where the overlay is set up:

```
    addImageOverlay: function(bounds, url, hidden) {
        var ne = new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.northEast.latitude,
                bounds.northEast.longitude);
        var sw = new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.southWest.latitude,
                bounds.southWest.longitude);
        var b = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);

        if(this.imageOverlay){
            this.imageOverlay.setMap(null);
            this.imageOverlay = null;
        }

        this.imageOverlay = new MapOverlay(bounds, url, this.map);

        this.imageOverlay.setMap(this.map);
        if (hidden === true) {
            this.imageOverlay.setMap(null);
        } else {
            this.imageOverlay.setMap(this.map);
        }

        return this.imageOverlay;
    }
```

The error I am getting is:

```
    Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null
    at MapOverlay.onRemove (MapOverlay.js:90)
```

From what I can tell so far, the onAdd() method does not appear to be getting called when I call setMap(map). Therefore, this.div is null when onRemove() is called (thus the NPE). Map is populated and valid as far as I can tell. Again, this is only happening in 3.32 and 3.33 of Google Maps API. I can't find any change in the documentation that would be causing this and have been stuck for a day now. I can stick with 3.31 for now, but it is supposedly being sunset in August.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?  If it isn't a bug in your code, you should create an issue in the [issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/support#issue-tracker)

Answer (score 0):

```
MapOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
    if (this.div && this.div.parentNode) {
        this.div.parentNode.removeChild(this.div);        
    }
    this.div = null;    
};
```

Added IF block and this will solves problem.
Please find the reference link below:-
1. https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/issues/393
2. https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/1083

Comment: Nayana, please don't add *"Me too"* as answers. It doesn't actually provide an answer to the question. If you have a different but related question, then [ask](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) it (reference this one if it will help provide context). If you're interested in this specific question, you can [upvote](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it, leave a [comment](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), or start a [bounty](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) once you have enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).